# Object [object global] has no method 'attachEvent'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, dom, microsoft-ajax

I have a WebForms page which is including MicrosoftAjax.debug.js (4.1.7.123) as a script resource:

```
// Name:        MicrosoftAjax.debug.js
// Assembly:    AjaxControlToolkit
// Version:     4.1.7.123
// FileVersion: 4.1.7.0123
// (c) 2010 CodePlex Foundation
```

On load this script self invokes, eventually calling this function:

```
var attachEvent = !!document.attachEvent;

...

function listenOnce(target, name, ieName, callback, isReadyState, isScript) {
    function onEvent() {
        if (!attachEvent || !isReadyState || /loaded|complete/.test(target.readyState)) {
            if (attachEvent) {
                target.detachEvent(ieName || ("on" + name), onEvent);
            }
            else {
                target.removeEventListener(name, onEvent, false);
                if (isScript) {
                    target.removeEventListener("error", onEvent, false);
                }
            }
            callback.apply(target);
            target = null;
        }
    }
    if (attachEvent) {
        target.attachEvent(ieName || ("on" + name), onEvent);
    }
    else {
        if (target.addEventListener) {
        target.addEventListener(name, onEvent, false);
        }
        if (isScript) {
            target.addEventListener("error", onEvent, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in Chrome I'm getting the following Javascript error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'attachEvent'**

On the following line:

```
target.attachEvent(ieName || ("on" + name), onEvent);
```

Attaching the debugger, `target` is the window object, which as you'd expect does not have the `attachEvent()` method in Chrome.

`document.attachEvent()` is the following function:

```
function (sType, fHandler) {
        var shortTypeName = sType.replace(/on/, "");
        fHandler._ieEmuEventHandler = function (e) {
            window.event = e;
            return fHandler();
        };
        this.addEventListener(shortTypeName, fHandler._ieEmuEventHandler, false);
    }
```

Is this a bug in the Microsoft Ajax script? Chrome? Or is it being caused by some condition on the page?

Either way, how can I resolve it?

Comment: What is `document.attachEvent`? (in the console)

Comment: Well, Chrome doesn't have `attachEvent`, that's an IE method. So the question is, why does `!!document.attachEvent` seem to evaluate to `true`?

Comment: I've updated my question regarding document.attachEvent

Comment: Where does that function come from? You probably don't want to define it since that makes the other script think it runs in IE.

Comment: @FelixKling I have no idea, I'll check to see if there are any conflicting libraries.

Comment: @FelixKling I've found it. It's coming from a legacy js library that we no longer require. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reassign `document.attachEvent` to begin with, so you may want to get rid of that.  `attachEvent` is true because of that.  That doesn't mean that `target.attachEvent` exists, though.  It seems like you should check `if (!!target.attachEvent)` before calling it on `target` instead of just looking at your `attachEvent` variable.

Comment: You're correct in that the document.attachEvent is being reassigned. However the code is a script resource within the AjaxControlToolkit. I could update the source on codeplex I guess, but will just remove the offending library doing the reassign for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this question up in case anyone else runs into the same problem. However the error was being caused by a legacy Javascript library reassigning the `document.attachEvent()` method.

This was the offending code:

```
function emulateAttachEvent() {
    HTMLDocument.prototype.attachEvent = 
    HTMLElement.prototype.attachEvent = function (sType, fHandler) {
        var shortTypeName = sType.replace(/on/, "");
        fHandler._ieEmuEventHandler = function (e) {
            window.event = e;
            return fHandler();
        };
        this.addEventListener(shortTypeName, fHandler._ieEmuEventHandler, false);
    };
    HTMLDocument.prototype.detachEvent = 
    HTMLElement.prototype.detachEvent = function (sType, fHandler) {
        var shortTypeName = sType.replace(/on/, "");
        if (typeof fHandler._ieEmuEventHandler == "function")
            this.removeEventListener(shortTypeName, fHandler._ieEmuEventHandler, false);
        else
            this.removeEventListener(shortTypeName, fHandler, true);
    };
}
```

Fortunately, I was able to remove the legacy library. However this won't help if you have a genuine case for reassigning the `document.attachEvent()` method, in which case you will need to come up with an alternative solution.